# How to make a Javascript DropTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to determine the best way to create a treeview list in a dropdown. I have found many JS controls of treeview's, but not how to implement in a dropdown list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dropdowns with treeviews in them, what you should be searching for is a "Hierarchical Dropdown".  Here's a good one:

http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm

Comment: Yes, I am using this plugin, however not sure how to implement inside a dropdown list control